# Can I use a number value for grid-template-rows / grid-template-columns?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am programatically creating a grid with rows and columns from my data.

However, when the data is a number (e.g. 0900) the style fails to be set on the element.

Is this because numbers can't be used, or a bug?

Code example:

```
this.myElement.style.gridTemplateRows = "[xHeader] 2fr [0900] 1fr [0930] 1fr 
[1000] 1fr [1030] 1fr [1100] 1fr [1130] 1fr [1200] 1fr"
```

Then, check the value: 
`console.log(this.myElement.style.gridTemplateRows)`.

It shows a blank result in devtools.

Comment: i think you can't use numbers in the first position because it will assume an actual numerical value, not a name. It will then resolve this value as having no unit, making the list incorrect.

Comment: If all else fails you can always prefix the number with a string of your choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the value doesn't begin with a number.

---

Named grid lines use the `<custom-ident>` (custom identifier) syntax<sup>1</sup>.

Per the rules of this syntax, `<custom-ident>` *"represents any valid CSS identifier that would not be misinterpreted as a pre-defined keyword in that property's value definition"* <sup>2</sup>.

The key term in the phrase above is *"any valid CSS identifier"*. So what are valid CSS identifiers?

Here's the answer:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+0080 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit.<sup>3</sup>

Note the part: ***they cannot start with a digit...***

---

Spec references:

<sup>1</sup> CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1, [§ 7.2.1 Named Grid Lines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#named-lines).

<sup>2</sup> CSS Values and Units Module Level 3, [§ 3.2 Author-defined Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#custom-idents)

<sup>3</sup> CSS Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2), [§ 4.1.3 Characters and case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#characters)